# Android text not showing

Tags: java, android

I have a program I am working on in Android studio. I am having an issue when getting the input from a user and setting it to a text box. Here is what im working with.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_onetap);

   // A BUNCH OF STUFF UP HERE

    final TextView username_textBox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.usernameTextBox);

    //check for username
    askForUsername();
    username_textBox.setText(readFile("username.txt"));


    // A BUNCH OF STUFF DOWN HERE

}
```

Here is the `askForUsername()` method

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Enter a username (You may not change this)");

    // Set up the input
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    // Specify the type of input expected
    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_NORMAL);
    int maxLength = 16;
    input.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength)});

    builder.setView(input);

    // Set up the buttons
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            username = input.getText().toString();
            saveFile("username.txt",username);
        }
    }).create();
    builder.show();
```

In this case `username` is a class-wide variable.
Whenever I run `askForUsername` i put in my username and the box called `username_textBox` doesnt display the username entered. I know my `readFile` and `saveFile` work because I use them for other things.

Comment: I know you say `readFile` works, but for sanity's sake have you checked to see what it is returning?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the onClick Event with a debugger?

Comment: `readFile` does return a string; i havent had problems reading with it in the past. I have not debugged the `onClick` event. I feel like its a problem where the system doesnt wait for the `askForUsername` function to finish because the `// BUNCH OF STUFF DOWN HERE` gets run already when im entering in the username. Is there a way to "update" or "re render" the `username_textBox` after I set it?

Comment: Do you want the other stuff to run while the user enters the username or have that action block the other stuff?

Comment: Im fine if it blocks that thread until finished but i'd like to know how to do it with blocking and without in case i need to do it without in the future.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience I think that it's not running in sequence. 
The `readFile("username.txt")` is being called during the dialog is showed.

What I would do is implement a method onPositiveResult with the DialogBuilder that handles the event of pressing "OK".

I can elaborate if needed.

---

Your Activity must tend a bridge between the Dialog and the Activity, this could be done with an Interface like this

```
public inteface myDialoglistener { 
    public void stuff( String param);}
```

then the askForUsername(Activity myAct) should recieve the Activity or Context as a parameter, that way you have access to the interface. Then you modify your Positive method to this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    username = input.getText().toString();
    saveFile("username.txt",username);
    myDialoglistener activity = (myDialogListener)myAct
    activity.stuff();
    }
```

Finally on your Activity you must override `stuff` method

```
@Override
public void stuff() {
     //your settext code here
}
```

Regards!

Comment: I would like you to elaborate just to make sure we're on the same page

Answer (score 0):

What happens here is that **askForUserName()** is not blocking, so **readFile** gets executed while the dialog is still opening, much before **saveFile** gets called.
A simple solution to show it in a TextView would be to make **username_textBox** a class variable and access it directly from dialog's **onClick** method:

```
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        username = input.getText().toString();
        username_textBox.setText(username);
        // if you need to save it in a file
        saveFile("username.txt",username);
    }
```

So your activity class would look something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView username_textBox;
    String username;         

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_onetap);

       // A BUNCH OF STUFF UP HERE

       username_textBox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.usernameTextBox);

        //check for username
        askForUsername();



    // A BUNCH OF STUFF DOWN HERE

    }

    void askForUsername(){       
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
         builder.setTitle("Enter a username (You may not change this)");

         // Set up the input
         final EditText input = new EditText(this);
         // Specify the type of input expected
         input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_NORMAL);
         int maxLength = 16;
         input.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength)});

         builder.setView(input);

         // Set up the buttons
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                username = input.getText().toString();
                username_textBox.setText(username);
                saveFile("username.txt",username);
            }
        }).create();
        builder.show();

    }
```